# How internally ModelState.IsValid is executed in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ALLOCATION_M allocationM)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    allocationM.ALLO_ID = GetId();
                    _unitOfWork.AllocationMRepository.Insert(allocationM);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", EditorLocalization.AllocationMasterController_Create_Unable_to_save_changes__Try_again__and_if_the_problem_persists__see_your_system_administrator_);
            }

            return View(allocationM);
        }
```

How internally C# run-time  checks `ModelState.IsValid`? I mean how it checks my model state is valid or invalid when the post method is called from the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the default model binder attempts to instantiate the model that is passed as argument to your controller action (prior to executing this action) from the request values if there are some validation errors it will add them to the ModelState. So once the execution flow enters your controller action there will already be validation errors added to it. The IsValid property simply checks whether there are elements in the Errors collection.

For example let's suppose that your `ALLOCATION_M` had a property decorated with the `[Required]` attribute:

```
[Required]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

When you submit the form in order to invoke this controller action if there's no parameter called `SomeProperty` in the request or if it is empty, the default model binder will add a validation error associated to this property.